# Dockerize Django App and Apache2 with Docker

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to `Dockerize` my `Django Web App` with `Docker` in order to migrate it to my production server.

This server is based to `Linux Ubuntu 16.04` and I would like to install `Apache2` into my container.

I found different way to use Docker, particulary to this github repository : https://github.com/ramkulkarni1/django-apache2-docker

But there is too few documentations about Docker with Django and Apache2 configurations to a new production server.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FIRST PART - My tree project :
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

```
DatasystemsCORE
├── API_GED
├── Authentification
├── Configurations
├── DatasystemsCORE
├── App1
├── App2
├── App3
├── App4
├── lib
├── static
├── templates
├── wsgi.conf
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
├── start.sh
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SECOND PART - Files according to Docker :
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

So I created a **Dockerfile** :

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-utils vim curl apache2 apache2-utils
RUN apt-get -y install python3 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
RUN ln /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN apt-get -y install python3-pip
RUN ln /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install django ptvsd
ADD ./demo_site.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
EXPOSE 80 3500
CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]

FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1 
ADD ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt 
RUN pip install -U pip && 
LIBRARY_PATH=/lib:/usr/lib /bin/sh -c "pip install -r /requirements.txt --no-cache-dir" RUN mkdir /code WORKDIR /code ADD ./src . 
EXPOSE 8000

ADD ./start.sh /start.sh
RUN chmod +x /start.sh
```

Then, I have a **docker-compose.yml** file :

```
version: "2"

services: 
  django-apache2:
    build: .
    container_name: django-apache2
    ports:
      - '8005:80'
      - '3500:3500'
      - '8006:81'
    volumes: 
      - $PWD/www:/var/www/html

  db:
    image: mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=DatasystemsCORE
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db-persistance:/var/lib/mysql

  django-app:
    build: .
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=django-app
      - DATABASE_NAME=DatasystemsCORE
      - DATABASE_USER=django
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=django
      - DATABASE_HOST=db

    entrypoint: /start.sh
    command: python3 /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8005
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I created a start.sh file too :

```
ADD #!/bin/bash
python3 /code/manage.py migrate && python3 /code/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
exec "$@"
```

In order to set up `Apache2` configuration, I have **wsgi.conf** file :

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE

<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE

        Alias /static "/var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/static"

        <Directory /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/static>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all denied
        </Directory>

        <Directory /usr/share>
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/DatasystemsCORE/DatasystemsCORE/wsgi.py

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

And finally I have a **requirements.txt** file which contains all dependancies according to my Django project.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
THIRD PART - Create dockerizing image and build image to my prod server :
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

In this part that I have some questions. 
I don't know if my docker files are well-written.

Then, I don't know what commands I have to execute.

I tried :

```
docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject DatasystemsCORE DatasystemsCORE
```

I get : `ERROR: No such service: web`

My process is good or I have to make that differently ?

Comment: Lots of this doesn't make sense. You already have a project, why are you trying to run startproject in your container? Why does your django-app container use runserver when you want to serve your site via Apache?

Comment: @DanielRoseman You're right, but I'm a bit lost with documentations found on the web and none doc are showing container from an existing Django project and Apache2 configuration.

Comment: you should start docker-compose in production with `docker-compose up -d` and not with run, your dockerfile is very bad too, you should try to use `&&` in your RUN so it produces just one layer, there is already python image, i would rather use that... docker has tutorial for django and postgres, i suggest you start there https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/

Comment: Thank you for your answer @MazelTov. I will read your doc but I have one question. If I want to export my web app to different servers How I could make that with Docker  ?  And How I could automatically configure apache  ?  With Docker or bash file  ?

Comment: I have created a github [reposotory](https://github.com/JoseManuelVargas/django-docker-apache2) explaining how you can deploy a django app using docker, python 3.8 and apache2. In this case I used miniconda3 in order to manage python packages. This is because this way it is easy to solve some users and permissions problems. And It uses a localhost postgresql database. It is up to you embedding the database as shown in the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/). Hope this can be useful to you.